# How can I create a Wizard interface from code injected via MEF?

Tags: c#, mvvm, mef, wizard

I would like to write Wizard on the basis of MVVM, MEF. 
I would like that each page of the Wizard was loaded from separate dll (MEF).
I found this excellent [article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9keqK.jpg) about creation of the wizard, but unfortunately in this article is not written as to use MEF for addition of pages.
I want to make the wizard just as described in the article but I can't think how to export page of the wizard using MEF.

---

I wrote a simple application to illustrate my problem.
This solution contains two assemblies.

[image]

How can I get a fully-formed page from the assembly WpfApplication4.Library in WpfApplication4.

I mean PageView with installed PageViewModel.

[Mef](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=4e1f0617c9aaf89e&resid=4E1F0617C9AAF89E!116)

Answer (score 2):

The article describes having a list of viewmodels, you could define a contract for your pages `IWizardPage` for example and then import such a list using the `ImportMany` attribute:

```
...
[ImportMany]
IWizardPage[] Pages{ get; set }
```

(the actual `IWizardPage` interface can be empty if you want)

Then you can add those pages like the article describes to the actual wizard main window

Comment: Thank you very much. But I don't understand how to connect View and ViewModel in the article used DataTemplate. But how can I connect the View and ViewModel if I use Mef?

Comment: Check out the prism guidance, http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/55580.  There are many examples of using mef to connect the view and viewmodel.  Essentially you just export the ViewModel and write a property on your View which imports that same view model and sets it as the DataContext of the view.